# How do I reload the values of multiple select boxes with jQuery StickyForms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, multipleselection

I'm using jquery [stickyForms](http://www.jqbyte.com/StickyForms/) to make some form values sticky, so that the user's entered values are restored to a form when the user returns to that form.

It's works great, except I can't get it to work with my multiple selects. I checked the cookies it creates, and it doesn't even set the right values. Looking at the code, it doesn't even appear to support multiple selects.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took it upon myself to add support for multiple selects. This works for me!

I changed line 115 to:

```
}else if(this[i].type == "select-multiple"){
    var setVal = $(this[i]).val();
}
```

Then I added this after line 178:

```
// Load multiples
if((this[i].type == "select-multiple") && val != "null" ){
    var val_list = val.split(",");
    var select_name = "#" + $(this[i]).attr("id");
    $(val_list).each(function(){
        $(select_name + " option[value="+this+"]").attr('selected','selected');
    });

}
```

It works! But mind you, I'm not an expert at javascript or jQuery, so if you have a more succinct solution or one with better performance, please let me know!

Comment: I spoke to the plugin's creator, Ryan Schwartz. He said they're going to include my update in their 1.0 release, along with Ajax-based form support.

Answer (score 1):

This is Ryan from JQByte, I wanted to let you know that we released version 1.0 of StickyForms today which includes support for multi-select and AJAX-processing forms.

http://www.jqbyte.com/StickyForms/

We did incorporate your solution into the plugin, we thank you for your contribution!

Cheers,
Ryan

Comment: Thanks for a great plugin! :)

Note: I tried to use this plugin in conjunctions with [toChecklist](http://www.scotthorlbeck.com/code/tochecklist/) but everything broke down when trying to save the cookie(s). I had to disable toChecklist, but would love to have it back since, as you can see from the example in the top right corner, it actually makes multiple selects easy to use! 

Would appreciate any insight you could offer.